# which is more efficient making Database triggers or handling all trigger events at front end

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008, database-trigger

I am working in a c#.net application
I am working on a project of school management

I had some entries in more than one tables some times so is it better to handle this in front end or I should use database trigger for this .
can you tell which thing is better in performance and time efficient

Comment: You seem to not particular care about correctness of data... In this case maybe you don't need any triggers at all?

Comment: i need corrctness of data

Comment: [(fast, good, cheap) - pick two](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Project_triangle)... If correctness is concern I see not much choice as go with DB  triggers (nvoigt have more details) as it is unlikely for your project to have sufficient budget for correct implementation on frontend (which may not necessary be any faster)...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If those triggers affect database integrity or data integrity (checking things, inserting other records, making backup copies of records before modification or maybe something else) then it should be database triggers, because you never know how many of your frontends will operate on the database at a given time and syncronizing them by yourself is a huge pain in the ... and it's also prone to errors while you already have a less-painful and less error-prone method at hand.